# How to avoid SqlException if SQL query contains reserved keyword?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, keyword

```
string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Table"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table", con))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                da.Fill(dt);//This line throws exception
                return dt;
```

I have this piece of code that I want to use to get selected data from grid and insert in another table. While debugging, it leads me to exceptions at `da.Fill(dt);` line.

Following is the exception being thrown:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.

Comment: You shouldn't use the name Table for a table as it 's a reserved word for sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the exception says, „Table“ is a keyword in SQL. If you want to use it as table name in your query,  you have to change your select statement to

```
SELECT * FROM [Table]
```